# Why is my text not being rendered within text components?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and i am having trouble with the following error message:

`text string must be rendered within a <Text> component`

This is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button } from "react-native";


const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
  <View>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Hey!</Text>
    <Button title='Go components demo'/>
  </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

My strings are wrapped within a Text component and the error message persists. Any typo am i not seeing or doing anything wrong?

Comment: You are not showing something, I'm not seeing any error with the code provided. https://snack.expo.dev/5DSSi7c4b

Comment: i did Ctrl + A and selected all the code and pasted it in here. I do not know why is this happening. I re runed npm start and i still have the same error. @mxmissile

Comment: you can try to wrap text into {"Hey!}.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is likely somewhere else in your app. one way to test this is to comment out the  component inside of your App component or wherever your Homescreen component is being called. It's more likely that wherever you're mounting HomeScreen, there is extraneous text. Perhaps something you missed when deleting the boilerplate code.

Answer (score -1):

Give some width and height to your view ,or try give a flex of 1 :
Hope it helps.

```
 <View style = {{flex:1}}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Hey!</Text>
    <Button title='Go components demo'/>
  </View>
```

or

```
 <View style = {{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Hey!</Text>
    <Button title='Go components demo'/>
  </View>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).